# Angular X-editable and custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, x-editable

look at this example :  ( [On jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnoj5fe3/) )

html part :

```
<div ng-app="AppModul" ng-controller="AppController">
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<div counter-directive max-length="100" ng-model="name"></div>
<a href="#" editable-text="name">{{ name || 'click on me' }}</a>
</div>
```

Js part :

```
var app = angular.module('AppModul', ["xeditable"]);
app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('counterDirective', function() {

  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      maxLength: '=',
      ngModel: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      console.log(scope.maxLength);

      scope.$watch(scope.ngModel, function(value) {

        if (value) {

          var newValue = value.length;
          console.log(value);
          element[0].innerText = newValue;
        }
      });

    }
  }

});
```

If you type in normal text input , by one directive u can see how many letters you typed , in the real time . Now click on editable link and type something . Nothing happens and directive does not work. Actually angular-xeditable does not update the ng-model in the real time unless  i click on save button .

How can i have the same behavior as text input tag in Angular-xeditable ?

Comment: Your example is working as expected. Do you want to customize the default behavior of `x-editable`?

Comment: if u click on editable link tag and type something in the text input , it does not work like normal input tag and it does not show the count of letter which has been typed by user .

Comment: [Just have a look at this example](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-simple). This is the default behavior of `x-editable`.